# How to setup pytest in my python virtual environment

Tags: python

I follow the steps in https://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Python/virtualenv.html to setup a python virtual env in my directory by doing `python -m venv testEnv` And I did `source venv/bin/activate`. I am on MacOSX and zsh.

But when I do `pytest`, i get error like

```
 $ pytest                      
zsh: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pytest: bad interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3: no such file or directory
```

And these are my python and pytest

```
❯ which python                  testEnv
python: aliased to /Users/hap497/.pyenv/shims/python
❯ which pytest                  testEnv
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pytest
```

So what do i need to do to setup python and pytest in my Virtual env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did

```
python -m venv testEnv
```

Then you wanted

```
source testEnv/bin/activate
```

And not

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

We can see in the `which` output that pytest is not correctly installed to your venv.  Activate the testEnv correctly and install pytest again.

Comment: After i activate , i did `which pytest` which points to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pytest`,  and `which python` and `which pip` both points to the right python which is `/Users/hap497/testEnv/bin/python`. But when I pip install pytest, pytest still points to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pytest`

Comment: And I do see `pytest` in my virtual env, `/testEnv/bin/pytest`, I don't understand why when I `which pytest`, it is not using `/testEnv/bin/pytest` but `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pytest`

Comment: Your shell might have cached the previous pytest target.  Try `hash -r` to invalidate the caches.

Answer (score 1):

After your virtual environment is activated run `pip install pytest`

Here is an example of running my conftest.py function that prints "A" before my test function that prints "B".

cd to the parent directory, for this example it is py_tests and run.

```
pytest tests\tests.py -s -v
```

The output is:

```
A
setting up
B
PASSED
```

---

With directory structure:

```
py_tests
 -conftest.py
 -tests
  --tests.py
```

---

Files:

```
conftest.py
```

---

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def print_one():
    print("\n")
    print("A")
```

---

```
test.py
```

---

```
import pytest

class Testonething:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, print_one):
        print("setting up")

    def test_one_thing(self):
        print("B")
        assert True
```